# Finding strings not already in a link with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string format that we commonly use to link between items `#12345` where the format is a hash followed by 5 to 7 numbers.

I'm trying to write an autolinker that will convert these strings into a link to the appropriate object:

```
<a href='http://foo.bar/12345'>#12345</a>
```

However, I can't just search for `#\d{5,7}` as some of the Ids may have already been converted into links.

How can I find all instances that aren't already within a anchor tag?

Comment: Did you consider using an HTML parser? Surely you could append a lookahead like `(?![^<]*</a>)` to your pattern but it is too error prone.

Comment: A parser feels like overkill for this personally.  It feels like that this should be a simple find/replace in JS.

Comment: If I get you right you want to match the pattern `#1234` which wasn't transformed in a link already, right ? If yes, why not to add an *not followed by* rule, e.g. `#\d{5,7}(?!<\/a>)` ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown that seems to work fine.  Thanks

Comment: @NeilMiddleton posted as an answers if you don't mind =)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a *not followed by* rule to get only those patterns which wasn't already transformed in a link:

```
#\d{5,7}(?!<\/a>)
```